# numpy: alternative numpy.take version

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following scenario:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(range(300)).reshape((3,100))
idxs = [10, 92, 22]
```

now I would like to get from the `ith` index, the element in the `ith` list of data. A possible solution is

```
[d[i] for d,i in zip(data, idxs)]
>>> [10, 129, 222]
```

my question now is, **is there any build in numpy function, that does exactly above functionality?** I have tried `np.take` but it outputs the values only out of the first list:

```
np.take(data, idxs)
>>> [10 29 22]
```

another solution with `np.take` includes `np.eye`, but it looks like an overkill compared with the list comprehension:

```
np.take(data, idxs, axis = 1)[np.eye(, dtype = np.bool)]
>>> [ 10 129 222]
```

**EDIT** the question looks like code golf for me now, so if it is the wrong place to ask it, give me feedback please

Comment: You could do : `data[np.arange(data.shape[0]),idxs]`.

Comment: that looks interesting, thank you :) suggestion from me: data[np.arange(len(idxs)), idxs]

Comment: Are you looking for a  *code-golfy* solution?

Comment: actually not, I was curious, whether there is a built-in numpy function, that already does this. Looks like not, so the solution is to use the indexing in clever way, am I right?

Comment: No, there's isn't any built-in for that. For more info, you can refer to - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing

Comment: ok, since I think, that it really could be a duplicate, should I mark it for deletion?

Comment: Ah, I am not sure if there's any harm with the deletion. Surely there's some good attempts in the question itself, so I would keep it!